# Php Table to display records with specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get a specific query to work based on the id sent to another page and produce a table of items belonging to a specific person.
I have 2 different tables a person table that list the person and primary key of id. On the 2nd table vehicles, i have a primary key of vehicleid and a id that is the person id. the table does not filter the responses to the specific person. In the menu bar i have upd** and the id of the person example upd=15, every every wayi have tried to get the php to work to produce a list of vehicles just belonging to that person has failed. I have lost track of how many tutorials and blogs i have looked at.

Example of the start of my Code. ***

```
<?php require "config/config.php"; ?> 

<?php if(isset($_GET['upd'])){ $id = $_GET['upd']; $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicles 
WHERE id=$id"; $fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("Can not fetch the data.".mysqli_error($con)); $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire); } ?>
```

Comment: ***Example of the start of my Code.                                                                                   
***<?php require "config/config.php"; ?>
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['upd'])){
  $id = $_GET['upd'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id=$id";
  $fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("Can not fetch the data.".mysqli_error($con));
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire);
  }
?>

Comment: Well, yes, hard to tell really with none of your code. Btw, you can EDIT your question and paste relevant data there, not in the comments. Thx

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lag="en"> 
<?php require "config/head.php"; ?>
<body>
 <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php       
    $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicles";
     $fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from datase ".mysqli_error($con));
      if(mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0){
      while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)){ ?>
   </tr>
    <td><?php echo $user['year'] ?></td>
   </tr>
    <?php
     }
     }
    ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Don't put code in comments, put it in the question. Use the code formatting option to make it readable.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Help please I am Learning

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.name, p.other_person_info, v.car_make, v.car_model From person as p 
Left Join vehicles ON p.id = v.id WHERE p.id = '15'
```

In other words, LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left table regardless of whether a row from the left table has a matching row from the right table or not. If there is no match, the columns of the row from the right table will contain NULL. So person is represented as p and vehicles table is represented as v and it will only output where your person id is equal to 15

Answer (score -1):

you are vulnerable of SQL Injection. I suggest study PDO.

Regarding to your question. Below are the codes:

```
<?php
  include('DBHOST','localhost'); //if you are using localhost
  include('DBNAME',''dbname); //your dbname
  include('DBUSER','root'); //username of your localhost
  include('DBPASS','yourpassword');

  try
   {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql: host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4; dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     $qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_yourtable";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($qry);
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
      die("Error Connection".$e->getMessage());
     }
     ?>
```

then in your table:

```
     <?php
      foreach($result as $value)
      {
       echo '<tr>
           <td>' .$value['id']. '</td>
           <td>' .$value['name']. '</td>';
      }
      ?>
```

Just like that.

Comment: Your example doesn't show any benefit of PDO  and doesn't implement the same algorithm as in the OP which makes it rather unusable